# How to combine the LIKE function with a DATE_PART function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, sql-like, datepart

Using Postgres, but if someone knows how to do this in standard SQL that would be a great start. I am joining to a table via a character varying column. This column contains values such as:

```
PC11941.2004
PC14151.2004
PC21213.2003
SPC21434.2003
PC17715.04V1
PC18733.2002
0MRACCT_ALL.GLFUNCT
```

A lot of the numbers after the periods correspond to years. I want to join the table via the current year. So, for example, I could `JOIN` on the condition `LIKE '%2015'`. 
But I want to create this view and never return to it so I would need to join it against something like `(get_fy_part('YEAR', clock_timestamp())`.

Not sure how I go about writing that. I haven't had success, yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current year with date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn LIKE ('%' || date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE))
```

The || operator concatenates the percent-sign with the year.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `RIGHT()`.

```
SELECT originalColumn, RIGHT(originalColumn,4)
FROM table;
```

This will get you the years you are interested in.

If you want everything after the dot, then something like:

```
SELECT originalColumn, RIGHT(originalColumn,len(originalColumn)-position('.' in originalColumn))
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the *exact* rules - and actually implemented `CHECK` constraints for the column.

If there is always a single dot in your column `col` and all your years have 4 digits:

### Basic solution

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE  col LIKE to_char(now(), '"%."YYYY');
```

#### Why?

It's most efficient to compare to the same data type. Since the column is a [character type (`varchar`)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html), rather use [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) (returns `text`, which is effectively the same as `varchar`) than [`EXTRACT` or `date_part()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) (return `double precision`).

More importantly, this expression is [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). That's generally cheapest and allows (optional) index support. In your case, a trigram index would work:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

### Optimize

If you want to be as fast (read performance) and accurate as possible, and your table has more than a trivial number of rows, go with a specialized [partial expression index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes.html):

```
CRATE INDEX tbl_year_idx ON tbl (cast(right(col, 4) AS int) DESC)
WHERE col ~ '\.\d{4}$';  -- ends with a dot and 4 digits
```

Matching query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE  col ~ '\.\d{4}$'  -- repeat index condition
AND    right(col, 4)::int = EXTRACT(year FROM col);
```

Test performance with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

You could even go one step further and tailor the index for the current year:

```
CRATE INDEX tbl_year2015_idx ON tbl (tbl_id)  -- any (useful?) column
WHERE col LIKE '%.2015';
```

Works with the first "basic" query.
You would have to (re-)create the index for each year. A simple solution would be to create indexes for a couple of years ahead and append another one each year automatically ...

This is also the point where you consider the alternative: store the year as **redundant `integer` column** in your table and simplify the rest.
That's what I would do.